# check if row contains nan pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, nan

I have dataframe `df` with 5 rows and 3 columns, indexed by date:

```
OA_Year 0   1   2       
1968    12.0 2.0 NaN
1969    2.0 1.0 1.0
1970    8.0 4.0 2.0
1971    8.0 4.0 2.0
1972    0.0 3.0 1.0
```

I'm trying to write a `for` loop that will add the entries in column 0 and 1 if column 2 contains a value of `NaN`. For now, I left the result equal to something simpler to test if the loop works.

```
for i in range(5): 
    if df.iloc[i, 2] == np.nan: 
        result = np.nan
    else: 
        result = 'False'
    print(result)
```

Instead of getting a list with `NaN` and 'False', I'm only getting a result of 'False'.
This is what I'm trying to get:

```
1968 NaN
1969 False
1970 False
1971 False
1972 False
```

Comment: "that will add the entries in column 0 and 1 if column 2 contains a value of `NaN`". Do you want to add the entries if column 2 is `nan`, or return `nan` if it is `nan`?

Comment: add entries, NOT return ```nan```!

Comment: But your `for` loop does the opposite: `if df.iloc[i, 2] == np.nan`.

Answer (score 1):

As the requirement is unclear, see whether this is what you want:

Add the entries in column `0` and `1` to column `2` if column `2` contains a value of `NaN`:

Here, we use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill up the `NaN` values in column `2` with the sum of the 2 columns `0` and `1`:

```
df['2'] = df['2'].fillna(df['0'] + df['1'])
```

Or use:

```
df['2'] = df['2'].fillna(df[['0', '1']].sum(axis=1))
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   OA_Year     0    1     2
0     1968  12.0  2.0  14.0
1     1969   2.0  1.0   1.0
2     1970   8.0  4.0   2.0
3     1971   8.0  4.0   2.0
4     1972   0.0  3.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you need, but generally - you don't necessarily need a for loop to achieve what you want. For example, this will sum the values in columns 0 and 1 for which column 2 does not contain `nan`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993], '0': np.random.rand(4), '1': np.random.rand(4), '2': [np.nan, 1, 2, 1]})
df[~df['2'].isna()][['0','1']].sum(axis = 1)
```